# Deduping a table while keeping record structures

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I've got a weekly process which does a full replace operation on a few tables. The process is weekly since there are large amounts of data as a whole. However, we also want to do daily/hourly delta updates, so the system would be more in sync with production.

When we update data, we are creating duplications of rows (updates of an existing row), which I want to get rid of. To achieve this, I've written a python script which runs the following query on a table, inserting the results back into it:

```
QUERY = """#standardSQL
            select {fields}
            from (
              select *
              , max(record_insert_time) over (partition by id) as max_record_insert_time
              from {client_name}_{environment}.{table} as a
            )
            where 1=1
            and record_insert_time = max_record_insert_time"""
```

The `{fields}` variable is replaced with a list of all the table columns; I can't use `*` here because that would only work for 1 run (the next will already have a field called `max_record_insert_time` and that would cause an ambiguity issue).

Everything is working as expected, with one exception - some of the columns in the table are of `RECORD` datatype; despite not using aliases for them, and selecting their fully qualified name (e.g. `record_name.child_name`), when the output is written back into the table, the results are flattened. I've added the `flattenResults: False` config to my code, but this has not changed the outcome.

I would love to hear thoughts about how to resolve this issue using my existing plan, other methods of deduping, or other methods of handling delta updates altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use in the outer statement

`SELECT * EXCEPT (max_record_insert_time)`

This should keep the exact record structure. (for more detailed documentation see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-except)

Alternative approach, would be include in `{fields}` only top level columns even if they are non leaves, i.e. just `record_name` and not `record_name.*`

Comment: Holy moly! Is that a unique BQ feature? Never encountered that syntax before! Also don't see it in the documentation.

Comment: You can read about it the [`Query Syntax` topic](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-except).

Answer (score 0):

Below answer is definitely not better than use of straightforward [SELECT * EXCEPT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-except) modifier, but wanted to present alternative version

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, MAX(record_insert_time) AS max_record_insert_time, 
    ARRAY_AGG(t) AS all_records_for_id
  FROM yourTable AS t GROUP BY id
),  UNNEST(all_records_for_id) AS t
WHERE t.record_insert_time  = max_record_insert_time
ORDER BY id
```

What above query does is - first groups all records for each `id` into `array of respective rows` along with `max value for insert_time`. Then, for each id -  it simply flattens all (previously aggregated) rows and picks only rows with insert_time matching max time. Result is as expected. No [Analytic Function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#analytic-functions) involved but rather simple [Aggregation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#aggregate-functions). But extra use of [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest) ...
Still  - at least different option :o)

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Small clarification - from my experience with BigQuery, when one aliases a table and performs a select using the table alias without a second alias to rename the selected column (e.g. `t.field` vs `t.field as field`), the output will always concat `t_` to each field name. However, my experience is mostly limited to the legacy SQL, so perhaps this is handled differently in standard SQL. Will this not be the case?

Comment: this is correct for legacy sql. but in standard sql t_ is not added. so you will get exactly original structure/naming